# НЕ получается с переключением класов

Tags: jquery

вот HTML

```
<button type="button"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="ion-android-add"></span>
</button>
```

вот jquery

```
$('#custom-bootstrap-menu.Two button').click(function(){
        var a = $(this).find('span').attr("class");
        alert(a);
            $(this).find('.ion-android-cart').removeClass().addClass("ion-android-add");
            $(this).find('.ion-android-add').removeClass().addClass("ion-android-cart");
    })
```

первый клик класс меняется, а второй клик клас остается уже ion-android-cart и не меняется. Почему и как это исправить ?

Comment: А зачем Вам `find()`? Может быть лучше воспользоваться `toggleClass()`: если класс есть - он уберется; если его нет - добавится...

Comment: @ cyadvert  мне надо один стереть а другой записать и не только один.

Comment: @cyadvert да кстати делаю так $(this).find('.ion-android-add').toggleClass("ion-android-cart");  класс просто добавляется и не удаляется

Comment: @cyadvert  и так тот же эфект $(this).find('.ion-android-add').toggleClass("ion-android-add ion-android-cart");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой вариант подойдет?

```js
$('#custom-bootstrap-menu button').click(function() {
  $(this).children().eq(0).toggleClass("ion-android-add").toggleClass("ion-android-cart");
  
})
```

```css
button>span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.ion-android-add {
  background-color: red;
}
.ion-android-cart {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
    <span class="ion-android-add"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```